# std::declare_if or other hypothetical ways for discarding member declarations at compile time

Tags: c++, c++17, sfinae, c++20

SFINAE is quite useful to discard function bodies, but why it can't be used to discard member variables?

Is such functionality planned to be added to modern C++ at some point, ever? I tried using `std::enable_if`, `std::conditional` (which would work if it was allowed to have a type of zero size, but would probably break everything else).

I'd love to be able to generate aliases using a hypothetical SFINAE pattern like:

```
template<class T, SIZE> 
struct Vector {
    union {
        T mArray[SIZE] = {};
        struct {
            std::declare_if<SIZE >= 1, T>::type x;
            std::declare_if<SIZE >= 2, T>::type y;
            std::declare_if<SIZE >= 3, T>::type z;
        };
    };
};
```

I don't see any adequate reasons for this not to exist at this point, except lack of compiler support?
If you have any idea for an elegant workaround or solution, without adding additional size to the union, or writing boilerplate code, such as a base, and then partially specialized derivations. 
I'd love to know.

Comment: "*I don't see any adequate reasons for this not to exist at this point*" I don't understand what you mean by that. The C++ language does not allow a type definition to turn into nothing. SFINAE is a thing that exists for template instantiations; it doesn't exist for non-template constructs like a non-template variable declaration. It doesn't exist because the language has no mechanism to allow it to exist.

Comment: Besides, even if it worked, what you're trying to do with your union will not be supported in standard C++ anyway. Arrays and structs are not layout compatible, nor do they have a common initial sequence, so you cannot access `Vector.x` and `Vector.mArray[0]` as though they're both talking about the same thing. At least, not as far as the standard is concerned.

Comment: FWIW what you are trying to do is illegal.  You are not guaranteed the struct and the array have the same memory layout.  While it will work in practice, it is UB.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the feedback. I didn't know that this practice is UB in the first place. I've used it many times without a hickup, but didn't realize its considered UB.

Comment: Isn't it UB only if types inside union aren't POD? Or is it always UB because it relies on implementation?

Comment: Even if I explicitly do #pragma pack push & pop to make sure everything is tightly packed?

Comment: I still don't see, how the mentioned member variable is not part of a template instantiation, and how it is considered a "non-template variable declaration", since it is inside a template? The whole Vector struct is a template and doesn't exist prior to being summoned and instantiated. I don't really see a problem of instantiating it, depending on its template arguments and completely deterministic behavior, with and without 'z'.
I can achieve that whole functionality by doing some inheritance and partial specializations. But that means I have to write a ton more code than I'd like to.

Comment: That's because the "SFINAE" trick relies on the rules of the *immediate* (so the thing must *be* a template, not just *in* a template) context of substitution when *looking for* (that's the important part) a function overload or a template specialization. In plain words, the outcome if a substitution failure is not "it doesn't exist" but "it won't fit, find another one", which is not enough firepower to volatilize a member and its name ahead of any mention.

Comment: [Andrei Alexandrescu's _"The next big Thing"_](https://youtu.be/tcyb1lpEHm0?t=2720) touches on the feature you're requesting here, and is a good watch.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve pretty much what you want with the help of the [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) attribute [`[[no_unique_address]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/no_unique_address),
which:

> indicates that this data member need not have an address distinct from all other non-static data members of its class. This means that if the member has an empty type (e.g. stateless Allocator), the compiler may optimise it to occupy no space.

Applied to your use case:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, int SIZE>
struct Vector
{
  T x;
  [[no_unique_address]] std::conditional_t<(SIZE > 1), T, decltype([]{})> y;
  [[no_unique_address]] std::conditional_t<(SIZE > 2), T, decltype([]{})> z;
};

int main()
{
  static_assert(sizeof(Vector<double, 1>) == 1 * sizeof(double));
  static_assert(sizeof(Vector<double, 2>) == 2 * sizeof(double));
  static_assert(sizeof(Vector<double, 3>) == 3 * sizeof(double));
}
```

Here I've used `decltype([]{})` as an empty type, yielding different types, so that they can share the same address.

Comment: Oooh, very smooth use of a lambda there!

Comment: Neat! I didn't know that

Comment: Yeah, dear lord indeed, I absolutely didn't anticipate, that having an empty type is actually possible, even with the newest standards

Comment: @DimoMarkov: It's *entirely* implementation defined whether this works or not. That is, a conforming C++20 implementation could ignore `[[no_unique_address]]` *entirely* if it so choose. It could ignore them for any number of reasons.

Comment: I understand this, however I'm optimistic, that new standards will significantly improve the language. It's only in interest of implementations to conform to that, since its exceptionally easing, and consistent as well. In other words, it's hardly something that takes something from anyone. It only benefits.

Comment: @NicolBolas That's right. Fortunately, it is quite straightforward to test whether the compiler did the expected thing at compile time (at least in this use case). And sincerelly I don't expect the compilers to ignore this attribute. GCC demo: https://godbolt.org/z/K5GG1J

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible right now but you can write a templated `get()` function which accepts integral value. Also, if you are using C++ 17, you can use structured binding too.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

// not elegant way of naming as enum will polute the whole namespace where it is defined
enum Idx {
    X = 0,
    Y = 1,
    Z = 2,
    W = 3,
    R = 0,
    G = 1,
    B = 2,
    A = 3
};

template <typename T, std::size_t SIZE>
struct Vector
{
    template<std::size_t Index>
    T& get() {
        static_assert(Index < SIZE, "Invalid Index");
        return data[Index];
    }

    template<std::size_t Index>
    const T& get() const noexcept {
        static_assert(Index < SIZE, "Invalid Index");
        return data[Index];
    }

    T data[SIZE];
};

//only needed if structured binding is required
namespace std {
template<typename T, size_t SIZE>
struct tuple_size<Vector<T, SIZE>> {
    constexpr static size_t value = SIZE;
};

template<typename T, size_t I, size_t SIZE>
struct tuple_element<I, Vector<T, SIZE>> {
    using type = T;
};
}

int main()
{
  Vector<int, 2> value = {0, 1};
  std::cout << "x = " << value.get<X>() << ": y = " << value.get<Y>() << '\n';

  // structured binding, available only in C++17
  auto& [x, y]  = value;
  std::cout << "x = " << x << ": y = " << y << '\n';

  // will generate a compiler error
  //auto& [x1, y1, z1] = value;

  // will invoke the static assert
  //auto z = value.get<Z>();
  return 0;
}
```